# GoogleServicesAPI - the app doesn't check if GPS is enabled

Tags: android, gps

I am trying to get my application to access Locations through the GooglePlayServices.

I have got my application to connect with the internet, but I have ran aground to a problem when I realised the phone does not check whether GPS is on or not.

If the GPS is on, the phone automatically starts updating. However, when the GPS is off, the phone doesn't react at all.

I have researched and have come across onProviderEnabled, but I only saw that it works for LocationManager, and am not sure if it applies to GooglePlayAPI as well.

**How do I get my application to check if the GPS is on or not?**

onConnected():

```
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You have connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationClient, mLocationRequest, this);

        Location NewLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mLocationClient);

        //Getting initial location and time
        PhoneBelt.setNewLocation(NewLocation);
        long NewLocationTime = new Date().getTime();
        PhoneBelt.setNewLocationTime(NewLocationTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code, it uses googleSettingsAPI to check if location is enabled or not. If not, it will display a dialog similar to google maps:

```
    protected void buildLocationSettingsRequest() {
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
    builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
    mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build();
    }


    protected void checkLocationSettings() {
    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(
                    mGoogleApiClient,
                    mLocationSettingsRequest
            );
    result.setResultCallback(this);
    }


@Override
public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {
    final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();

    switch (status.getStatusCode()) {


        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
            Log.d("FragmentCreate", "All location settings are satisfied.");

            pd.show();


            try {

                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);


            }catch (SecurityException se){
                Log.d("FragmentCreate","You don't have permissions");
                pd.dismiss();
                errortext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                errortext.setText("Please provide Location permission to continue, Settings->Apps->RecommendedApp->Permissions");
                Toast.makeText(this,"Please provide location permissions to continue",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


            break;


        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
            Log.d("FragmentCreate", "Location settings are not satisfied. Show the user a dialog to" +
                    " upgrade location settings ");

            try {
                // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the result
                // in onActivityResult().
                status.startResolutionForResult(TabbedResult.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                Log.i("FragmentCreate", "PendingIntent unable to execute request.");
            }
            break;



        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
            Log.d("FragmentCreate", "Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be fixed here. Dialog " +
                    "not created.");
            break;
    }
}
```

mGoogleApiClient is your googleApiClient object you built and LocationSettingsRequest is the request you use to get the provider

Comment: So do I just call this in onConnected?

Comment: build the locationsettings in onCreate and call checkLocationSettings in onConnected

Comment: do make sure that you build the LocationSettingsRequest, your actual LocationRequest and the GoogleApiClient in onCreate before calling the check in onConnected